# Linux shell script "unable to access jarfile"

Tags: linux, shell, jar, debian, chmod

I have a jar file in the /root directory of a debian 11 VPS. I am having trouble creating a startup shell script.

The contents of the script (/etc/init.d/runjar.sh) are as follows:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo "Running Jar"
java -jar /root/bot.jar

exit 0
```

I had ran both "chmod +x /etc/init.d/runjar.sh" and "update-rc.d runjar.sh defaults". When I restarted the VPS, the jar did not run.

I tried running the script through the terminal "sh /etc/init.d/runjar.sh" and was met with the response:

```
root@api:~# sh /etc/init.d/runjar.sh
: not found/runjar.sh: 2:
Running Jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile /root/bot.jar
: not found/runjar.sh: 5:
```

I have made sure the permissions were set using "chmod +x /root/bot.jar" and "chmod 777 /root" to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sh`  you can use the `service` command because the `runjar.sh` is palced in the init.d folder.

Comment: `systemctl start runjar` throws an error still, checking the status says it failed to execute `runjar.sh`

Answer (score 0):

### 1. run a new script for a test

`echo -e '#!/bin/sh\necho "Running Jar"\ndate && echo "successful"' > /etc/init.d/runjar.sh`

`sh /etc/init.d/runjar.sh`

if output info is successful,then it proved the env of shell is fine

### 2. rewrite your script

`echo -e '#!/bin/sh\necho "Running Jar"\njava -jar /root/bot.jar\nexit 0' > /etc/init.d/runjar.sh`

`chmod +x /etc/init.d/runjar.sh`

`sh /etc/init.d/runjar.sh`

and check the output info.